# Mac C++ #include cannot find file installed by homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

After I install gflags by homebrew, I try to compile a project by there is a error:

> fatal error: 'gflags/gflags.h'.

Then I try to test gflags by writting a simple program like this(just include the gflags):

[image: the code]

and I use g++ to try to compile the file and I still get the same error:

[image: the error]

But I find gflags in /usr/local/include/gflags/gflags.h indeed.
And I try glog which is also installed by homebrew, and get the same error.

The problem is g++ can't find the file in /usr/local/include. Can somebody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not as link to images please.

Comment: `gcc -I /usr/local/include test.c -o main`

Comment: You seem to be mixing C and C++. Try to stick to one or the other.

Comment: I wonder why homebrew installed it in `/usr/local/include` but for me it is in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/local/include` to the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` variable

In your shell:
`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include"`

Comment: Mac M2: `/opt/homebrew/include/`